# From C++ how to execute a method or access struct which is in C?

Tags: c++, c, linux, struct

I need to pass string value from C++ to C library. 
How do you call `CppCallToC` or from .cpp how can i access the `struct rtmp_stream *stream;` ?

C++ file: UI/window-basic-main.cpp:

```
void OBSBasic::Load(const char *file) {
  //From C++ how to go to the C method?
  CppCallToC();
}
```

C file: plugin/obs-outputs/rtmp-stream.c:

```
static void CppCallToC() {

  //https://github.com/jp9000/obs-studio/blob/master/libobs/util/dstr.h
  //struct dstr      path, key;
  struct rtmp_stream *stream;
  //dstr_printf(&stream->path,  obs_path);
  //dstr_printf(&stream->key,   obs_key);
}
```

Comment: `std::string` and references aren't `c`.

Comment: 1. You can't access local variables in a different function; 2. You can't call that function anyway – and you're not supposed to – since it's static; 3. This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is not a C vs C++ issue. All functions in rtmp-stream.c are declared static, which means they have internal linkage and cannot be called from a different compilation unit. You can only access those functions indirectly via the rtmp_output_info struct defined at the end of the file and declared in [obs-outputs.c](https://github.com/jp9000/obs-studio/blob/master/plugins/obs-outputs/obs-outputs.c), and even that declaration is only available within that file.

I don't know anything about OBS Studio, so I can't help you any more than that, I'm afraid. You'll have to track down what happens in `obs_register_output(&rtmp_output_info)`.